# Hardware acceleration on chrome kiosk using ubuntu server

Tags: intel, graphics

I've purchased the Intel NUC5PPYH in order to make it a chrome kiosk. The CPU is Intel Pentium N3700 which has Intel HD Graphics built in. The kiosk is built on top of **Ubuntu Server 14.04.3** with `xorg`, `openbox` and `google-chrome-stable`.

I got the kiosk running with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session & 

while true; do
    rm -rf ~/.{config,cache}/google-chrome
    google-chrome  —-disable-translate \
    —-disable-infobars \
    —-disable-suggestions-service \
    —-disable-save-password-bubble \
    —-disable-restore-background-contents \
    —-disable-vertical-tabs \
    —-disable-answers-in-suggests \
    —-disable-extensions \
    —-disable-new-kiosk-ui \
    —-disable-notifications \
    —-disable-plugin-power-saver \
    —-kiosk —-no-first-run ‘somewebsite.com‘
done
```

I also have a conf file in the init.d directory, `/etc/init.d/kiosk.conf`:

```
start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [06]

console output
emits starting-x

respawn

exec sudo -u USERNAME startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh —-
```

Until this point everything worked exactly as expected. When the chrome browser is launching and I go to `chrome://gpu` I can see that almost every option has the `Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable` near it. I browsed to `chrome://settings` and ensured that the hardware acceleration is checked. Also, I browsed to `chrome://flags` and made sure to enable the `Override software rendering list`. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I still see the `Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable` message.

I tried to google around and look for a solution for this but no avail. I have some suspicious that the Intel HD Graphics driver isn't installed or at-least isn't installed correctly. When I run the command `lspci | grep VGA` I see

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
```

I ran the command `lshw` and checked the `display` section and saw that this controller clock speed is 33Mhz which isn't right for the built-in GPU that comes with the processor. The GPU should have 400MHz base speed and burst to 700MHz. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that I don't get hardware acceleration.

I would like someone to shine some light on this issue and tell me what I'm doing wrong :/

Comment: Does the acceleration work when you run ubuntu desktop (live usb)? Since you're running ubuntu server, the drivers may not be included.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got hardware acceleration on my intel device and it should work on your kiosk.
Since your kiosk is intel based, you can try vdpau hardware acceleration.
you can download my hardware acceleration script [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u9a51cr70kkcnvc/haccel) Then use `sudo cp path/to/file/haccel /bin/` and run `sudo chmod +x /bin/haccel` allow it to run. Then run chrome with `haccel google-chrome <Whatever settings you need/want>` or run `vdpau_driver=va_gl google-chrome <Whatever settings you need/want>` if you don't want to use my script.